# Class as function parameter in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In Angular 2 testing utility I do something like this:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditableValueComponent);
```

where EditableValueComponent is a normal component class.

I wonder how it works:

```
static createComponent<T>(component: Type<T>): ComponentFixture<T>;
```

Beceause I wanna do something similar (I want to simplify some testing stuff):

```
export class SuperFixture<T>
{  
    fixture: ComponentFixture<T>;
    component: T;

    constructor()
    {         
        this.fixture = TestBed.createComponent(T); // <--- problem here!
        this.component = this.fixture.componentInstance;   
    }
}
```

The problem is:

> 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.'

EDIT #1

I solved the problem this way:

```
constructor(component)
{
    this.fixture = TestBed.createComponent<T>(component);
```

But I still don't know how it works..

Answer (score 0):

You still need to pass actual class (constructor function that creates instances of a class) into constructor function of `SuperFixture`. Under the hood `TestBed.createComponent` calls provided constructor function with `new` to create instance of provided class. So `SuperClass` signature might look like this:

```
class SuperFixture<T>
{
  fixture: ComponentFixture<T>;
  component: T;

  // passing in the constructor for instances of T
  constructor(componentConstructor: new () => T)
  {
    this.fixture = TestBed.createComponent<T>(componentConstructor);
    this.component = this.fixture.componentInstance;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Was working on that answer, but had to step out for coffee. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

The language feature you are using is called a [Generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in TypeScript. It allows defining types at runtime with "*type variables*" (like `<T>`), which are separate from function arguments.

Before, the **type variable** was being passed as a **function argument**, when the function expected an instance of type T. That's what the error means.

The change you made works because you are passing the type variable and the instance in their correct positions in the call.

The `SuperFixture` object gets the value of `T` when you create it, and then it will pass that type variable to `createComponent` in the constructor, along with the value of `component`.